# Showing Recent Messages Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift

When I use this code I got error

> Showing Recent Messages
>   Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

```
// keyboardWillShow / keyboardWillShow
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollview.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
    self.scrollview.contentInset = contentInset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
}

// scroll view textField
func animateTextField(textField: UITextField, up: Bool)
{
    let movementDistance:CGFloat = -175
    let movementDuration: Double = 0.3

    var movement:CGFloat = 0
    if up
    {
        movement = movementDistance
    }
        else
    {
        movement = -movementDistance
    }
    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    self.animateTextField?(textField: textField, up:true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    self.animateTextField?(textField: textField, up:false)
}
```

CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift
    cd /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDResizableCropOverlayView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/feedVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/postVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/navVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/postCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/commentCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/usersVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/ViewController.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/newsCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/pictureCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/guestVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signUpVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/uploadVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/commentVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/followersCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropViewController.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropOverlayView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/followersVC.swift -primary-file /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/homeVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/newsVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/AppDelegate.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDCropBorderView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImagePicker.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/resetPasswordVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/headerView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/tabbarVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/editVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/hashtagsVC.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/Instragram-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram -emit-module-doc-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Instragram -emit-module-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.swiftdeps -o /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.o

/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:33:84: error: use of local variable 'keyboardWillShow' before its declaration
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
                                                                                   ^
/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:40:14: note: 'keyboardWillShow' declared here
        func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
             ^
/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:34:84: error: use of local variable 'keyboardWillHide' before its declaration
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
                                                                                   ^
/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:49:14: note: 'keyboardWillHide' declared here
        func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
             ^
/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:37:41: error: cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Bool'
        textField.resignFirstResponder()?
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

```
0  swift                    0x0000000108c5176b llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 43
1  swift                    0x0000000108c50a56 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 70
2  swift                    0x0000000108c51dbf SignalHandler(int) + 287
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8d5ca52a _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fd822cc0bc0 _sigtramp + 2507105968
5  swift                    0x0000000106f48033 swift::TypeBase::getMemberSubstitutions(swift::DeclContext*) + 435
6  swift                    0x0000000106f48300 swift::TypeBase::getTypeOfMember(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::Type, swift::DeclContext*) + 64
7  swift                    0x0000000106d7d207 (anonymous namespace)::CalleeCandidateInfo::CalleeCandidateInfo(swift::Type, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::constraints::OverloadChoice>, unsigned int, bool, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem*) + 647
8  swift                    0x0000000106d77b61 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis, bool, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 9521
9  swift                    0x0000000106d70cc2 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 82
10 swift                    0x0000000106d75220 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 3872
11 swift                    0x0000000106dd9ee0 swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 736
12 swift                    0x0000000106de0aee swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 542
13 swift                    0x0000000106d79f84 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 1012
14 swift                    0x0000000106d76e34 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis, bool, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 6148
15 swift                    0x0000000106d70cc2 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 82
16 swift                    0x0000000106d75220 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 3872
17 swift                    0x0000000106dd9ee0 swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 736
18 swift                    0x0000000106de0aee swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 542
19 swift                    0x0000000106d79f84 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 1012
20 swift                    0x0000000106d85649 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckArbitrarySubExprIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>) + 633
21 swift                    0x0000000106d725b1 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 6465
22 swift                    0x0000000106d75220 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 3872
23 swift                    0x0000000106dd9ee0 swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 736
24 swift                    0x0000000106de0aee swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 542
25 swift                    0x0000000106d79f84 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 1012
26 swift                    0x0000000106d70d04 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 148
27 swift                    0x0000000106d75220 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 3872
28 swift                    0x0000000106dd9ee0 swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsiganed int>) + 736
29 swift                    0x0000000106de0aee enter code hereswift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 542
30 swift                    0x0000000106de1a54 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckBinding(swift::Pattern*&, swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*) + 100
31 swift                    0x0000000106de1bf9 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckPatternBinding(swift::PatternBindingDecl*, unsigned int) + 281
32 swift                    0x0000000106df5f1c (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::visit(swift::Decl*) + 556
33 swift                    0x0000000106df5cd1 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckDecl(swift::Decl*, bool) + 161
34 swift                    0x0000000106e327cd swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 381
35 swift                    0x0000000106e3141f swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckFunctionBodyUntil(swift::FuncDecl*, swift::SourceLoc) + 335
36 swift                    0x0000000106e31c7a swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBody(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 154
37 swift                    0x0000000106dc9c76 typeCheckFunctionsAndExternalDecls(swift::TypeChecker&) + 166
38 swift                    0x0000000106dca735 swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int) + 1397
39 swift                    0x0000000106c532d5 swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 3429
40 swift                    0x00000001067a2ed0 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 944
41 swift                    0x00000001067a1c79 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2777
42 swift                    0x000000010679d765 main + 1957
43 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff92ced5ad start + 1
44 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000005b start + 1831938735
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDResizableCropOverlayView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/feedVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/postVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/navVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/postCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/commentCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/usersVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/ViewController.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/newsCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/pictureCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/guestVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signUpVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/uploadVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/commentVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/followersCell.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropViewController.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImageCropOverlayView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/followersVC.swift -primary-file /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/homeVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/newsVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/AppDelegate.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDCropBorderView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/WDImagePicker.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/resetPasswordVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/headerView.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/tabbarVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/editVC.swift /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/hashtagsVC.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/Instragram-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Instragram-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram -emit-module-doc-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Instragram -emit-module-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.swiftdeps -o /Users/farisalbalwi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instragram-glveuyzasgixiqefeympuygiocza/Build/Intermediates/Instragram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Instragram.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signInVC.o 
1.  While type-checking 'keyboardWillShow' at /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:40:9
2.  While type-checking declaration 0x7fd8211a15f0 at /Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:42:9
3.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:42:36 - line:42:92] RangeText="(userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).c"
4.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:42:36 - line:42:92] RangeText="(userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).c"
5.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:42:37 - line:42:77] RangeText="userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]"
6.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/farisalbalwi/Desktop/Instragram/Instragram/signInVC.swift:42:37 - line:42:77] RangeText="userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]"
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: I didn't get error in specific line ! the error is ( Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 )

Comment: I'm assuming this happens when you compile?